# Observer won't fire when in behavior, will outside of behavior

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

Polymer 1.*

```
<script>
  AccountBehavior = {
    properties: {
      tabactivated: Boolean
    },

    observers: ['_refreshActivePosts(tabactivated)'],

    _refreshActivePosts: function(tabactivated) {
      if (tabactivated) {
          console.log('sss'); 
        this.$.account.refreshAjax();
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

`selected-attribute="tabactivated"` is from iron-pages.

The observer fires correctly when this code is placed in the two elements that uses it. But when placed in a  behavior and imported it will not fire. Why is this?

Comment: Please provide the whole implementation (i.e. how you use the behavior). Even better if you can provide an online demo.